# alldifferent/1 predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

```
allsame([]).
allsame([X]).
allsame([X,X|Z]) :-
   allsame([X|Z]).
```

How do I change to get the result below?

```
alldifferent(L): The elements in L are all different.

?- alldifferent([a, b, b, c, d]).
false
?- alldifferent([a, b, c, d, e]).
true
```

Comment: By using the search facility.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131904/check-if-all-numbers-in-a-list-are-different-in-prolog

Comment: The question could be made more interesting by asking what would be the most *efficient* way of calculating this. I'm not sure whether the `length/1`-method is faster/slower than working on a sorted list (with duplicates).

Comment: Are you looking for understanding on how to create `alldifferent/1` or are you really specifically wanting to know how it might relate to `allsame/1` (the answer given to you in a different question) and specifically how `allsame/1` could be morphed to be `alldifferent/1`? Finding the solution to a predicate like `alldifferent/1` may not look at all like solving `allsame/1`. Also, you should try to take what you've learned so far and apply it the problem. Start by writing down what you think it means logically for members of a list to be "all different" and then translate that to Prolog.

Comment: @magus@mbratch thank both of you. i think i figured out the solution. I was just looking for alldifferent/1 predicate then but now, I want to relate it with the allsame/1. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 6):

First, lets look at your definition of `allsame/1` first.  For a given list,
you are establishing equalities like so:

```
[ A,      B,      C,      D ... ]
    A = B,  B = C,  C = D,   ...      chain pattern
```

So you are establishing a chain of equalities. There is another way of expressing this, by referring to a common variable instead:

```
[ A,      B,      C,      D ... ]
  A = V,  B = V,  C = V,  D = V,  ... star pattern
```

This is most idiomatically expressed by:

```
allsame_bis(L) :-
   maplist(=(_), L).
```

Or, more prolix, without using the frequently defined [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682987/prolog-map-procedure-that-applies-predicate-to-list-elements/6683502#6683502):

```
allsame_ter(L) :-
   allsame_with(L, _).

allsame_with([], _).
allsame_with([X|Xs], V) :-
   X = V,                      % could be moved into the head
   allsame_with(Xs, V).
```

Now, you say, you "want to relate" this to `alldifferent/1`, which makes the situation even more complex. Note that `alldifferent/1` is not a direct negation of your property. That would be:

```
notallsame(L) :-
   phrase((..., [A,B], {dif(A,B)}, ...), L),
```

> There are two directly consecutive elements that are different.

For completeness, here is a version that avoids redundant answers for queries like `notallsame([1,2,3])`:

```
notallsame_bis(L) :-
   phrase((all(=(A)),[A,B], {dif(A,B)}, ...), L).
```

> There is first a sequence of identical elements, followed by an element that is different.

`all//1` and `... //1` are [defined elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971037/prolog-removing-unique-elements-only/21994498#21994498).

But back to alldifferent/2. The equality-relation is transitive, which permitted us to do some shortcuts, either doing a chain or a star. But being different is not transitive. So we have now to establish the difference relation `dif/2` between all possible pairs. In total, we need *n*2-*n*/2 many `dif/2` goals. Hey, let's be happy that we still can exploit commutativity, otherwise we would have to pay more than twice.

```
 alldifferent([]).
 alldifferent([X|Xs]) :-
    maplist(dif(X), Xs),
    alldifferent(Xs).
```

This relation establishes `dif/2` like so:

```
 [ A,      B,        C,        D,        E ... ]
       dif(B,A), dif(C,A), dif(D,A), dif(E,A), ... maplist(dif(A),[B,C,D,E ...])
                 dif(C,B), dif(D,B), dif(E,B), ... maplist(dif(B),  [C,D,E ...])
                           dif(D,C), dif(E,C), ... maplist(dif(C),    [D,E ...])
                                     dif(E,D), ... maplist(dif(D),      [E ...])
```

Here is another version, which might look seductively simpler. In fact, it has a certain resemblance to your original program. Has it not?

```
alldifferent_bis([]).
alldifferent_bis([_]).
alldifferent_bis([A,B|Xs]) :-
   dif(A,B),
   alldifferent_bis([A|Xs]),
   alldifferent_bis([B|Xs]).
```

So finally, we might use the following definitions using [a higher order definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950154/pairwise-relation-over-list):

```
alldifferent_ter(L) :-
   pairwise(dif,L).

allsame_quater(L) :-
   pairwise(=,L).
```

---

Should you, for whatever reason, not be able to use `dif/2`, use the safe ISO Prolog approximation [`iso_dif/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223390/prolog-a-person-is-a-sibling-of-himself/20238931#20238931) instead. It will succeed as often as (safely) possible, it might produce an error, when safe failure is possible, though. Think of `alldifferent_bis([_,a,a])`.

Comment: @mbratch: Thank you! My subconscious says: optimize this manually, and my reason says: `[B|Xs]` should be detected by the compiler as a common subterm - ok, systems do not do that now, but...

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `iso_dif/2`. I was lamenting a little that GNU didn't have a `dif/2`.

Comment: @mbratch: caveat added.

Comment: Every answer of SO should be like this. Great job!

Comment: Is it OK now? Completely confused.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
all_different( Xs ) :-
  all_different(Xs,[])
  .

all_different( []     , _ ) .  % if the source list is exhausted, success!
all_different( [X|_]  , S ) :- % if the list is non-empty
  member(X,S ) ,               % - if we've already seen X
  ! ,                          % - we cut and fail:
  fail                         % The list has duplicates
  .                            %
all_different( [X|Xs] , S ) :- % otherwise, we simply recurse down,
  all_different( Xs , [X|S] )  % prepending X to the "already seen" list.
  .                            % Easy!
```

Another way:

```
all_different( Xs ) :- setof( X , member(X,Xs), Xs ) .
```

A third way:

```
all_different( Xs ) :-
  msort(Xs,S) ,
  check_uniqueness(S)
  .

check_uniqueness([]) .
check_uniqueness([X,X|_]) :- !, fail .
check_uniqueness([_|Xs])  :- check_uniqueness(Xs) .
```

A fourth way:

```
all_different( Xs ) :-
  findall( X , (append(Pfx,[X|Sfx],Xs),(member(X,Pfx);member(X,Sfx))) , [] )
  .
```

There's more than one way to do it...some more efficient than others.

Comment: Your third way as it stated will always succeed, because `sort/2` removes duplicates. Change `sort` to `msort`.

Comment: Each version seems to behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do it:

```
all_different(Xs) :-
    sort(Xs, Sorted),
    msort(Xs, Sorted).
```

SWI-Prolog-style mode declaration:

```
%! all_different(+Xs:list) is semidet.
```

Comment: `all_different([X,a]), X = a` now succeeds. Either it should fail, or produce an error.

Comment: @false It's not intended to be used when the argument is not fully instantiated. I've added mode declaration to show this.

Comment: Above declaration rules out `all_different([a,b|_])` but does not rule out `all_different([X,a])`. And, if it would, what about `all_different([+X,+a])`?

Comment: @false Both `[X,a]` and `[+X,+a]` are not fully instantiated. The declaration requires the argument to be fully instantiated.

Comment: The declaration for `length/2` above only says: The `list` must be `+`. What you imply is: It has to be ground. Please show me where such a thing is required. Further this means that `all_different([+_,-_])` will not be considered by you.

Comment: @false According to SWI-Prolog documentation http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes, `+` in declaration means 'fully instantiated', i.e., not contain any variables.

Comment: And of course declaration should not be about `length`, but about `all_different` - I just copied this from SWI-Prolog docs and forgot to change.

Comment: The *entire sentence* reads: Argument must be fully instantiated to a term that satisfies the type. And [_] is fully instantiated for `list`.

Comment: @false `[_]` is not fully instantiated, it contains a variable. If it would be fully instantiated, we would check if it's a list. `a` is fully instantiated, but is not fully instantiated to a list.

Comment: @false I hope I communicated clearly that the predicate is not intended to be used when the argument is not fully instantiated.

Comment: Please read again the sentence: it says: fully instantiated to a term that satisfies the type.  Your reading would be expressed as: Ground.

Comment: @false 1. 'Fully instantiated' and 'ground' means the same. 2. 'Fully instantiated to a type' means 'fully instantiated and of a specified type'. That's my understanding. Are you disagree with 1 or 2 or both?

Comment: HET! Maybe agreement with 1 (under certain circumstances). But never with 2. The type is just `list`. And not `list_of_chars` or whatever. So the elements are not considered.