# prolog, checking if all members of a list are unique without built-in predicates

Tags: prolog

I want to write the rule unique(List) that checks if all elements in List are unique. I'm not allowed to use member, but I am allowed to use 'not'. Therefore I wrote the rule 'member' myself.

I wrote this:

```
member(Element, [Element|_]).
member(Element, [_|List]) :-
    member(Element, List).

unique([H|T]) :-
    not(in_list(H, T)),
    unique(T).
```

The member-rule is working, it checks if Element is a member of List. But the unique- rule doesn't work. For the unique-rule is was expecting it would check if H was in T and then do the same for the Header of the Tail and so on. The 'not' makes from a false statement a True-output.
When I run this rule with query    ?-unique([1,2,3,4,5])   it gives False. So what's my mistake?

Comment: `all_dif` at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724022/ will work correctly also with an open list, due to using `freeze`: ?- all_dif(L), L = [A,B|T], T = [C,D].

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131904/check-if-all-numbers-in-a-list-are-different-in-prolog

Answer (score -1):

I just discoverd the solutions a few moments later.
I added this above:

```
unique([]).
unique([_,[]]).
```

Comment: Consider `?- unique([[],[]]).` which should fail, but succeeds with this definition.

Comment: @ jack, you meant `unique([_|[]]).` which is just `unique([_]).`. you also meant to name your "`member`" predicate "`is_list`".